# How can I use Behat to make a Stripe purchase with the simple form?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, behat

I'm using this form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="YOUR PUBLIC KEY"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png"
    data-locale="auto">
 </script>
```

From https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/checkout

I've looked into making a custom form, but I'm not enjoying that alternative.  So my question is, is there a way I can make a Stripe purchase using Behat and that form?

Comment: umpirsky is right, IMO you should mock it following any of his suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock stripe service using [TuTu](https://github.com/coduo/TuTu) or some similar tool and use that in test env with Behat.

Another approach is to create dummy class that talks to this service which overrides one that does that in production mode and use it in test env instead.

You can also skip payment in test env.